# NSNull in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

`allItems` is an `NSMutableArray` and when the user clicks the plus button the method `createItem` gets called. I'm trying to only add objects (of the class `BNRItem`) for every even number index, so I tried putting an instance of `NSNull` for the odd number indexes:

```
-(BNRItem *)createItem {
    BNRItem *p = [[BNRItem alloc] init];
    if ([allItems count] == 0)
        [allItems addObject: p];
    else {
        [allItems addObject: [NSNull null]];
        [allItems addObject: p];
    }
    return p;
}
```

And the output after I clicked the plus button 3 times is this:

```
2012-09-03 13:20:13.876 Homepwner[718:f803] Index: 0 item: Laptop (123): Worth $60, recorded on (September)
2012-09-03 13:20:13.876 Homepwner[718:f803] Index: 1 item: <null>
2012-09-03 13:20:13.877 Homepwner[718:f803] Index: 2 item: Brush (234): Worth $14, recorded on (September)
2012-09-03 13:20:13.882 Homepwner[718:f803] Index: 1 item: <null>
2012-09-03 13:20:13.882 Homepwner[718:f803] Index: 4 item: Calculator (345): Worth $19, recorded on (September)
```

If I keep clicking the plus button the `<null>` object always remains at index 1 instead of incrementing to 3, 5, and so on. I was wondering why it's like this and how I can fix it.

Comment: Show the code that prints that.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong with your logging, but the items are going into the array correctly -- just log allItems, it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not showing the code for your logging, but, based on the results, I'd say you're doing something like:

```
for( id obj in arr ){
    NSLog(@"Index: %lu item: %@", [arr indexOfObject:obj], obj);
}
```

The `indexOfObject:` method finds the lowest index where `obj` is equal to an item in the array. Since `[NSNull null]` always gives you the same object (it's a singleton), when `obj` in the loop is the `NSNull`, `indexOfObject:` will always stop searching at 1.

The `for`-`in` loop will always go through your array in order, so you can just keep a counter to print the current index:

```
NSUInteger idx = 0;
for( id obj in arr ){
    NSLog(@"Index: %lu item: %@", idx++, obj);
}
```

or use a "regular" `for` loop:

```
NSUInteger count = [arr count];
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
    NSLog(@"Index: %lu item: %@", i, [arr objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Finally, the array will print itself and send `description` to each of its contained items if you just log it: `NSLog(@"%@", arr);`. This will be in order, so unless you really need the indexes attached, I'd suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Caswell's answer is right, but another way could be using [block-based enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW3), as you will be provided with the current index and the object.

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Index: %lu item:%@", idx, obj);
}];
```

---

This code

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[mArray addObject:@(1)];
[mArray addObject:@(5)];
[mArray addObject:@(7)];
[mArray addObject:@(1)];
[mArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
[mArray addObject:@(10)];
[mArray addObject:[NSNull null]];

[mArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%lu %@", idx, obj);
}];
```

will result in:

```
Index: 0 item:1
Index: 1 item:5
Index: 2 item:7
Index: 3 item:1
Index: 4 item:<null>
Index: 5 item:10
Index: 6 item:<null>
```

The benefit of this way is, that you have secure and fast enumeration with mutation blocking, while you also have the index without another (possibly faulty) lookup.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW3):

> For NSArray enumeration, the index parameter is useful for concurrent enumeration. Without this parameter, the only way to access the index would be to use the indexOfObject:

Comment: My god, it _just now_ dawned on me that this how you should translate `for i, o in enumerate(l):` from Python. Good thinking!